# How to load .obj file using ASSIMP into DirectX9

Tags: directx-9, assimp

I am new to 3D world, I have been learning DirectX9 to understand basics of graphics, meanwhile I intend to keep 3D programming cross platform as much as possible, therefore I am planing to use ASSIMP mesh importer rather than using native D3DXLoadMeshFromFileX.. function, however I can't find any neat tutorial on integrating ASSIMP into DirectX9.

Can you help me with this or Suggest any resource where ASSIMP integration is detailed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a lot of tutorials how to integrate Assimp into an OpenGL-based renderer ( for instance this one: [OpenGL-based rendering with Assimp](https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Assimp).

Or you can take a deeper look onto this post about the DX9.0 based rendering: [DX9.0 based Assimp-rendering](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/628674-assimp-and-direct3d-9/) .